# AChartGraph with multiple lines

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

I want to get some values from a table and store them in a multiple line chart. 
When I use only one column (fat) it displays a graph correctly, but when i add another column or two it gives me an error saying :
Dataset and renderer should not be null and should not have the same number of series.
Could you please help me fix the error?

```
  public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getFatDataset() {

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("select * from dailystats;", null);
    float i = 1.0f;

    c.moveToFirst();
    XYSeries seriesFat = new XYSeries("Fat");
    while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
        seriesFat.add(i++, c.getDouble(2));

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    dataset.addSeries(seriesFat);

   i = 1.0f;
    c.moveToFirst();
    XYSeries seriesProtein = new XYSeries("Protein");
    while(!c.isAfterLast()) {

        seriesProtein.add(i++, c.getDouble(3));

        c.moveToNext();
    }
    dataset.addSeries(seriesProtein);

    c.moveToFirst();
    i = 1.0f;
    XYSeries seriesCarbs = new XYSeries("Carbs");
    while(!c.isAfterLast()) {

        seriesCarbs.add(i++, c.getDouble(4));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    dataset.addSeries(seriesCarbs);

    return dataset;
}
```

And here is the code for generating the graph:

```
public class ChartActivity {

public Intent getIntent(Context context)
```

{

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();


XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

DatabaseAdapter dba = new DatabaseAdapter(context);
dba.open();


Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dba.getFatDataset(), mrenderer,"line graph");
dba.close();

return intent;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error reported is quite clear: `Dataset and renderer should not be null and should not have the same number of series` means that you're using a different number of series and series renderer. Infact, you're adding **two** datasets:

```
//...
dataset.addSeries(seriesFat);
//....
dataset.addSeries(seriesCarbs);
//....
```

But you only have **one** `XYSeriesRenderer()`:

```
mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
```

In my opinion your code should start working simply adding another renderer to the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer()`, please try with these two lines:

```
XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);
```